# Single Sign On - Asp.Net Identity not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on

I have three applications, "Login Application", "Application A" and "Application B". I used Asp.Net Identity for authentication and authorization. I need to implement a single sign on mechanism however most examples in the internet uses form authentication. I already added a machinekey in all my applications and I tried adding the code below,

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="singlesignoncookie" loginUrl="https://sample.com/Account/Login" timeout="12000"/>
</authentication>
```

This successfully redirects any unauthorized request to the login page in my "Login Application", however it seems like the authentication cookie doesn't work cause it just gets stuck in the login page even though the user credentials are all correct. I also tried adding the Cookie Domain property but still no luck.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    CookieDomain = ".sample.com",
    CookieName = "singlesignoncookie"
});
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated. Thank you.